# SystemJS doesn't move assets files to dist folder

Tags: angular, systemjs

Hi there I am trying to learn angular without using the cli to understand how the internals work. I am using `systemjs` as module loader. My question here is, does systemjs suppose to move the `.html` and `.css` files to `dist` folder along with compiled `.ts` files? Because if I want to use relative paths in my components I need to set `moduleId: module.id` in @Component decorator. Then when I load my browser it tries to get these assets from `/dist/app/app.component.html` which doesn't locate there.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "app-root",
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = "My First Angular App!";
}
```

**ts.config.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "outDir": "dist"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

**systemjs.config.json**

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {

  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    // our app is within the app folder
    'app': 'dist', // 'dist',

    // angular bundles
    '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',

    // other dependencies
    'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
    'rxjs-compat': 'node_modules/rxjs-compat',
    'core-js': 'node_modules/core-js',
    'zone.js': 'node_modules/zone.js'
  };

  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app': {
      main: 'main.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'rxjs': {
      main: 'index.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'rxjs/operators': {
      main: 'index.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
      main: 'index.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'core-js': {},
    'zone.js': {}
  };

  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];

  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = {
      main: 'index.js', 
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    };
  }

  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = {
      main: 'bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }

  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;

  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);

  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

I am using angular version 6 if it helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "No", some developers use gulp to do that.
I like this way, inside systemjs.config.json

```
map: {
  // our app is within the app folder
  app: 'app',
```

And in app.component.ts:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
```

See this for more details :
https://github.com/Longfld/AngularQuickStartForBeginning/blob/master/app/app.component.ts

Comment: gotcha. I was curios if moving assets is the general way

Comment: normally, use systemjs as development. If you want production performs, particular from  aot, jit, tree shaking, move assets is better

Comment: got it. Thanks a lot!